# Log file growth issues

Tags: sql-server-2008, transaction-log

We're consolidating data from a bunch of databases into four reporting databases each night.

Because the entire dataset is imported each night we do not need to be able to restore the data to a point in time. Thus the databases are in simple recovery mode.

Each time we run the import however, our database `ldf` files grow to absurdly large sizes (50+ Gigs).

Is there a way to turn off the logging altogether or get SQL Server to clear those log files sooner?

I'm guessing no for clearing as the `log_reuse_wait_desc` is `ACTIVE_TRANSACTION`.

Comment: What's the import mechanism or tool?

Comment: its a stored procedure that pulls data from a linked server access database and inserts it into a sql server database

Comment: Break it up into batches... as per Remus's answer (which appeared as I was typing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can import the data by using operations that can be minimally logged. See [Operations That Can Be Minimally Logged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Prerequisites for Minimal Logging in Bulk Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

And you should consider reducing the duration of transactions during the import. Use batches of limited size and commit periodically.